# Commutator operator for noncommutative partial derivatives

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, curvature

When studying evolution of a curve governed by
$$\frac{\partial\gamma}{\partial t}=\kappa\vec{N}$$
we find
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}L=-\int \kappa^2ds\implies \frac{\partial}{\partial t}ds=-\kappa^2ds$$
Following the text [here](http://mathematics.stanford.edu/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Mooney-Honors-Thesis-2011.pdf) [page 5]

"By the above computation, $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}ds=-\kappa^2ds$ It follows that
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\partial}{\partial s}=\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\frac{\partial}{\partial t} +\kappa^2\frac{\partial}{\partial s}$$
Using the commutator rule, we obtain..."

I do not understand the reasoning behind the last step. It means that
$$-\kappa^2\frac{\partial}{\partial s}=\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\frac{\partial}{\partial t} -\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\partial}{\partial s}$$

I understand that the partial derivatives in this case are not symmetric, as $s$ directly depends on $t$. Might someone please offer a derivation, so I can understand its meaning and how to arrive at it?

I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$v=\frac{\partial s}{\partial p}$$

We have

$$\frac{\partial p}{\partial l}\frac{\partial s}{\partial p}=v\frac{\partial p}{\partial l}$$
$$\implies$$
$$\frac{\partial l}{\partial p}\frac{\partial p}{\partial s}=\frac{1}{v}\frac{\partial l}{\partial p}$$

As the above holds for any $l$, we have

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial s}=\frac{1}{v}\frac{\partial }{\partial p}$$

We now apply $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ to the expression.

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\partial }{\partial s}=\frac{-1}{v^2}\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}\frac{\partial }{\partial p} + \frac{1}{v}\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\frac{\partial }{\partial p}$$

Now we need to find $\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}$.

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial p}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}L= \kappa^2\frac{\partial s}{\partial p}$$
Because $t$ and $p$ are independent of each other, derivatives commute 
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\frac{\partial}{\partial p}L= -\kappa^2\frac{\partial s}{\partial p}\land L=s$$
$$\implies$$
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial t}v= -\kappa^2\frac{\partial s}{\partial p}$$

Thus we get

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\partial }{\partial s}=\frac{1}{v^2}\kappa^2v\frac{\partial }{\partial p} + \frac{1}{v}\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\frac{\partial }{\partial p}$$

Which is equivalent to

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\partial }{\partial s}=\frac{\partial p}{\partial s}\kappa^2\frac{\partial }{\partial p} + \frac{\partial p}{\partial s}\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\frac{\partial }{\partial p}$$

as $v=\frac{\partial s}{\partial p}$. Finally arriving at

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\partial}{\partial s}=\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\frac{\partial}{\partial t} +\kappa^2\frac{\partial}{\partial s}$$